# How to Fix http error response 401 in ionic angular

Tags: angular, ionic6

I am trying to display an **error** alert when the user enters incorrect information but I get the error **401** instead of the error alert message.
My condition otherwise is not executed and I can't find a solution.
Thanks for any help.

the code in `home.ts`

```
async login(){
    if(this.form.valid){//verifie si le formulaire est renseigner
      if(this.form.value){
        const load = await this.loading.create({
          message: 'Connexion en cours...',
          cssClass: 'loadCss',
          spinner: 'dots',
        })
        load.present();
        this.authDta = {
          'telephone' : this.form.value.phone,
          'password' : this.form.value.password,
        };
        this.clientService.auth(this.authDta).subscribe(res=>{
          let resClient = res['client'];
          if(resClient.telephone && resClient.password)  {
            localStorage.setItem("client", JSON.stringify(resClient));
            load.dismiss();
            this.form.reset();
            this.route.navigateByUrl('/tabs');
          }else{
            load.dismiss();
            this.alertErreurLogin();
          }
        });
      }
    }else{
      const al = await this.alert.create({
        message:'Veuillez renseigner votre nom d\'utilisateur et le mot de passe SVP ?',
        position:'top',
        cssClass:'toast_cssErreur',
        duration:3000
      })
      al.present();
    }
  }
```

the `service` of authentication

```
public auth(data : any) : Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post(url + '/login', data);
    
  }
```

Comment: are you using the right credentials?

Comment: this is the goal I want to achieve, that is when the user makes a mistake with his credentials that the application displays an error.

Comment: `console.log` is your friend. find out what `resClient` is, then go from there.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're receiving an error before your code arrive to "res" of the subscriber ->

```
this.clientService.auth(this.authDta).subscribe(res=>{
      let resClient = res['client'];
      if(resClient.telephone && resClient.password)  {
        localStorage.setItem("client", JSON.stringify(resClient));
        load.dismiss();
        this.form.reset();
        this.route.navigateByUrl('/tabs');
      }else if(res == 'error'){
        load.dismiss();
        this.alertErreurLogin();
      }
    });
```

you can put a try catch in the service

```
public auth(data : any) : Observable<any>{
 try {
  return this.http.post(url + '/login', data);
 } 
 catch(err){
  return 'error';
 }
}
```